# How to prepare entitlements for NWJS to submit app to mac app store?

Tags: macos, mac-app-store, appstore-sandbox, nwjs, mach

I have signed files of a NWJS application package using a shell script for Nwjs 0.36 on MacOS 10.14.3. I want to upload a NWJS application to the Mac App store. However, the app crashes after signing it and trying to run it. I think it is due to a lack of permissions in the sandbox entitlements.

It is possible to replicate this issue by signing the default nwjs.app for MacOs without modification using a macOS developer identity. The list of files that I have included in the script are the ones listed by the MacOS "application loader", the application checking package submission to the Mac App store. It was required by the application that a list of programs should include sandbox. [https://developer.apple.com/app-sandboxing](https://developer.apple.com/app-sandboxing/)/

```
    #!/bin/bash
# copy this script in a file & run this by typing "sh thenameofthisfile" in Mac terminal
#directory is just the path name without app.
# app is yourapp without .app extension
#helpername is the name to replace= nwjs in nwjs help.app
#macosuseraccount is your macOS user account for the paths.
# "3rd party mac developer Installer" => for signing pkg // 3rd party mac developer Application => for signing everything in the app + .app
# replace app name / helpen name / macOs user name
#V1 is a variable equals to the current chromium version in the pathname for example: 71.0.3578.98

APP=nwjs
HELPERNAME=nwjs
MACOSUSERACCOUNT=nicolasguerinet

ID_APP="3rd Party Mac Developer Application"
ID_PKR="3rd Party Mac Developer Installer"
DIRECTORY=/users/$MACOSUSERACCOUNT/path/to/your/app
APP_PATH="$DIRECTORY/$APP.app"
PARENT_PLIST=$DIRECTORY/parent.plist
CHILD_PLIST=$DIRECTORY/child.plist
CHROMIUMVERSION=(/$APP_PATH/contents/versions/*/)
V1="$(basename $CHROMIUMVERSION)"

xattr -cr $APP_PATH

codesign --deep -s "$ID_APP" --entitlements "$CHILD_PLIST" "$APP_PATH/contents/versions/$V1/$HELPERNAME helper.app" -f -v
codesign --deep -s "$ID_APP" --entitlements "$CHILD_PLIST" "$APP_PATH/contents/versions/$V1/$HELPERNAME helper.app/contents/macos/$HELPERNAME helper" -f -v

codesign --deep -s "$ID_APP" --entitlements "$CHILD_PLIST" "$APP_PATH/contents/versions/$V1/nwjs framework.framework/versions/a/helpers/crashpad_handler" -f -v

codesign --deep -s "$ID_APP" --entitlements "$CHILD_PLIST" "$APP_PATH/contents/versions/$V1/nwjs framework.framework/Versions/A/Resources/app_mode_loader.app/Contents/MacOS/app_mode_loader" -f -v

codesign --deep -s "$ID_APP" --entitlements "$CHILD_PLIST" "$APP_PATH/contents/versions/$V1/nwjs framework.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/AlertNotificationService.xpc/Contents/MacOS/AlertNotificationService" -f -v

#codesign --force --verify -s "$ID_APP" --entitlements "$CHILD_PLIST" "$APP_PATH/Contents/Versions/$V1/nwjs Framework.framework/nwjs Framework"

codesign --deep --force --verify -s "$ID_APP" --entitlements "$CHILD_PLIST" "$APP_PATH/Contents/Versions/$V1/nwjs Framework.framework"

codesign --deep -s "$ID_APP" --entitlements "$CHILD_PLIST" "$APP_PATH/contents/versions/$V1/nwjs framework.framework/libnode.dylib" -f -v

#codesign -s "$ID_APP" --entitlements "$CHILD_PLIST" "$APP_PATH/Contents/MacOS/$APP" -f -v


codesign --deep -s "$ID_APP" --entitlements "$PARENT_PLIST" $APP_PATH -f -v
```

Here is my child.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.inherit</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

After signing the programs and the parent package, when i try to run the application crashes right away. I can find errors in my console when filter using "nwjs" or "process:sandboxd"

I think that the major error is:

> Sandbox: nwjs(4602) deny(1) network-bind
>
> /private/var/folders/kt/c216x7lx2qg87zhlwx46l6zr0000gn/T/io.nwjs.nwjs/.io.nwjs.nwjs.5zPGi8/SingletonSocket

I also get errors like this one:

> Sandbox: nwjs(4676) deny(1) file-read-data
>   /Users/nicolasguerinet/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist
>
> Sandbox: nwjs(4676) deny(1) mach-register io.nwjs.nwjs.rohitfork.4676
>
> Sandbox: nwjs(4676) deny(1) mach-register
>   io.nwjs.nwjs.FieldTrialMemoryServer.4676
>
> [0210/214619.981611:ERROR:mach_extensions.cc(68)] bootstrap_check_in
>   org.chromium.crashpad.child_port_handshake.6116.258959.GPSJQYHPOAJCMUEY:
>   Permission denied (1100)

and those two from the application:

> [0210/210429.187708:ERROR:directory_reader_posix.cc(42)] opendir: Operation not permitted (1)
>
> [0210/214620.466617:ERROR:mach_port_broker.mm(43)] bootstrap_look_up:
>   Permission denied (1100)

I guess that some permissions are missing in parents.plist and should be added to the parent.plist to make Nwjs runs after being code signed.

---

Update: 
I have added the following to my parents.plist without success:

```
<key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.sbpl</key>
<array>

        <string>(allow ipc-posix-sem)</string>
        <string>(allow file-issue-extension)</string>
        <string>(allow mach-lookup)</string>
        <string>(allow file-write-create)</string>
        <string>(allow file-read-data)</string>

</array>
```

Comment: did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @ZayinKrige unfortunately not.

Comment: 2 years later any clues on fixing that ?